# Getting only direct child pages in WordPress with get_pages

Tags: php, loop, pages, page-template

I am trying to fetch all direct children of a page. But I am getting all children and grand children as well. Any ideas?

**PHP Source:**

```
$args = array( 
        'child_of' => $post->ID, 
        'parent ' => $post->ID,
        'hierarchical' => 0,
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 
        'sort_order' => 'asc'
);
$mypages = get_pages( $args );

foreach( $mypages as $post )
{

$post_tempalte = the_page_template_part();

get_template_part( 'content' , $post_tempalte );
}
```

My `$args` should be correct according to the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages), but it's totally ignoring `parent` and `hierarchical`.

**My page structure is as follows:**

> Parent
>   -Child 1
>   -Child 2
>   --Child 1 to child 2
>   --Child 2 to child 2
>   -Child 3

And I only want to get `child 1`, `child 2` and `child 3`.

Comment: Try considering the `depth` option also.
another solution which I found and seems to be working is `$mypages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc&parent='.$post->ID);`

here you can change `sort_column` & `sort_order` as per need.

Comment: @RohitPande `depth` didn't help me at all, setting `child_of` and `parent` to the same it was.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please check the parameter 'parent'. It seems there is a space after the name.

Comment: Oh god. So stupid. But thank you, that saved me some time. :)

Answer (score 6):

With the parameter 'depth' of the "wp_list_pages" or the "get_pages" function, we can define how many levels do we want to retrieve. So here, I will display all the first child level of the current page.

```
            <?php global $post;
                    wp_list_pages( array(
                    'child_of' => $post->ID, // Only pages that are children of the current page
                    'depth' => 1 ,   // Only show one level of hierarchy
                    'sort_order' => 'asc'
                ));
            ?>
```

Comment: The get_pages function does not appear to have a depth argument, or at least it is not documented: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/.